# If $\textbf{P}(A) = 0.1$, $\textbf{P}(B) = 0.79$ and the probability of $A\cup B$ occurring is $0.85$, find the probability of $A\cap B$

Tags: probability, independence

If $\textbf{P}(A) = 0.1$, $\textbf{P}(B) = 0.79$ and the probability of at least one of $A$ or $B$ occurring is $0.85$, find the probability of both $A$ and $B$ occurring.

So I put down the "probability of at least one of $A$ or $B$ occurring" as $\textbf{P}(A\Delta B)$ and then tried to solve for $\textbf{P}(A\cap B)$.

But how do I find the answer without knowing $\textbf{P}(A\cup B)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

The probability of at least one event $A$ or $B$ to occur is given by $\textbf{P}(A\cup B)$, not $\textbf{P}(A\Delta B)$.

Having said that, you may be interested in the following relation:
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A\cup B) = \textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B)
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: ooh, that yeah that makes more sense, but why isn't it considered to be "the probability that A or B occurs but not both", does the question have to specifically state the "but not both" part? Just asking because the original question doesn't mention/imply the "or both" part that would be given for $\textbf{P}(A\cup B)$, hope that makes sense

Comment: In mathematics, the word "or" is inclusive. In the present context, the statement $A$  or $B$ occurs is the same as $A$ occurs, $B$ occurs or both $A$ and $B$ occurs. In colloquial language, sometimes the word "or" is exclusive as you have interpreted. But, once again, that is not the case in mathematics.

Comment: Right right, so I was just reading too much into it, thankyou~

Comment: @Alyna-KuteaeyvaXX you are welcome ! I am glad I could help.